# Set column as single in a Datagridview that reads data from a notepad

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, notepad

I'm programing in VB.net and I have a Datagridview that reads lines separated by ; from a notepad file using this code:

```
Private Sub ReadFile()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader("resource/database.txt")
    Dim strLineIn As String
    Dim strSplit() As String
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        strLineIn = sr.ReadLine
        strSplit = strLineIn.Split(";")
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(strSplit(0), strSplit(1), strSplit(2), strSplit(3), strSplit(4), strSplit(5), strSplit(6), strSplit(7), strSplit(8), strSplit(9), strSplit(10), strSplit(11), strSplit(12), strSplit(13), strSplit(14))
    Loop
    sr.Close()
End Sub
```

Now the problem is that all data is loaded as string, so numeric columns are being sorted in alphabetic order instead of numeric order. How can I read this specific colums as single? Or how can I convert them to single instead of string once they've been loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are various issues which are wrong (and/or not too right in your code). Firstly, relying on `StreamReader` right away (as you are using it) is usually a bad idea; it is better inside a `Using` statement, which will take care of everything (otherwise, you would have to make sure that the variable is disposed properly). Secondly, if you want to update all the contents in the `DataGridView` regularly, you should better rely on the `DataSource` property, rather than adding all the rows every time. Lastly, note that, when adding a new column to a `DataGridView`, its type has to be defined. .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not very experienced with VB.net; could you help me with the code I should use to do what you suggest? I must also say that the DataGridView will only show data; the user cannot edit the data, add columns, add rows, etc.

Comment: Writing a proper code to account for this specific problem wouldn't be helping you (neither future readers). This code denotes that you need to learn a bit more about I/O, DataGridView, types, etc. Just take my previous comment as a first step to know on which aspects you should focus your learning.

Comment: The code I wrote works perfectly fine. Now the only thing I'm asking is how can I do to sort one of the columns as numbers instead of text...

Comment: As explained, the code you wrote has various problems. Also I have told you how you can accomplish what you want: declare the desired type (i.e., numeric) when adding the columns to the `DataGridView`. Please, let's cut the conversation here. If you want to take my help, take it; otherwise, wait for other helper. Let's better stop wasting time unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I received help somewhere else. @varocarbas, the solution was as simple as adding "CDec" before the split of the column with decimal numbers. Now everything works fine. I hope this can be of help for people having the same issue.